# Docker + webdevops: "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

On a current project I use Docker. I must clarify that I am pretty inexperienced at it.

My project is a PHP/Symfony project. Until then, I used `nginx:alpine` and `phpdocker/php-fpm` to have my project running on my dev environment. However, I found these unfit to my case as my production actually uses Apache.

I found another project I'm on uses the `webdevops` Docker images without trouble. I want to replace the two containers listed above with a single one, the `webdevops/php-apache-dev:alpine` docker image.

Although the configuration between the two projects seems almost identical, my dev environment does not seem to work properly: I end up with this:

> This site can’t be reached - 172.18.0.7 refused to connect.

(I also use Traefik, but the routed URI does not work any better. The error message is slightly different though: `Bad Gateway`).

I find myself unable to debug this. I don't even know where to look.

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` configuration I want to use:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  app:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:alpine
    container_name: my-app
    working_dir: /app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /public
      WEB_DOCUMENT_INDEX: index.php

      LOG_STDOUT: ./var/log/app.stdout.log
      LOG_STDERR: ./var/log/app.stderr.log

      # @todo list of unwanted PHP modules, cf. https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache-dev.html#php-modules
      # PHP_DISMOD:

      php.error_reporting: E_ALL
      PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS: 1

      PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 80M
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 200M
      PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 521M
      PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 300

      PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE: Europe/Paris
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        # - ./docker/apache2/conf.d:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d
        - ~/.ssh:/home/application/.ssh:ro
        - ~/.composer:/home/application/.composer
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - database
```

The other containers work just as well as they did before. This one is the only one that fails.

When calling `docker-compose up` no error is thrown. All the logs I could find within the container remain silent. As far I as can tell, Traefik does not seem to be the problem. Here is the result of `docker ps`:

```
[/var/www/html/citizen-game]$ docker ps                                                                                              *[master] 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
6e9639e7a84d        webdevops/php-apache-dev:alpine                       "/entrypoint supervi…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours             80/tcp, 443/tcp, 9000/tcp                                                                    my-app-app
be1b90fdf768        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                                                           my-app-elasticsearch
76fb8743a12f        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin                                 "/run.sh supervisord…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours             80/tcp, 9000/tcp                                                                             my-app-phpmyadmin
dd41b4afe267        mysql:5.7                                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                                          my-app-database
91893783bcb1        rabbitmq:3.7-management                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours             4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   my-app-rabbitmq
63f551884bbf        traefik:maroilles                                     "/traefik --web --do…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

My question is, I guess: how can I debug this? Am I missing something trivial?

### Edit

Here is (part of) the content of the `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    app:
      volumes:
        - ~/.ssh:/home/application/.ssh
        - ~/.composer:/home/application/.composer
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=my-app"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-app.docker"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      networks:
        - internal
        - proxy
      environment:
        PHP_DEBUGGER: xdebug
        #XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: <your host IP address>
        XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT: 9000
        XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART: 1
        XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 1
        XDEBUG_PROFILER_ENABLE: 1
        XDEBUG_PROFILER_ENABLE_TRIGGER: 1000

    traefik:
      image: traefik
      container_name: citizen-game-traefik
      command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker --logLevel=DEBUG
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        - "8080:8080"
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      restart: always
      networks:
        - internal
        - proxy

    rabbitmq:
      networks:
        - internal
        - proxy

networks:
    proxy:
      external:
        name: traefik
    internal:
```

### EDIT 2:

@Mostafa

I ran the following:

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' my-app-app`

Result is:

`172.18.0.7172.19.0.5`

Trying these directly from the browser fails "This site can't be reached". I suppose it was to be expected.

I ran the following from inside the container:

```
bash-4.4# supervisorctl status apache:apached
apache:apached                   RUNNING   pid 13575, uptime 0:00:00
```

As suggested, I used `ss -plant | grep 80`. This does not work from within the container. Here is the result when called outside of it:

```
[/var/www/html/my-app]$ ss -plant | grep 80                                                                 
LISTEN      0        80              127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                                                                                      
ESTAB       0        0            192.168.1.88:39360      198.252.206.25:443     users:(("chromium-browse",pid=4203,fd=80))                                     
SYN-SENT    0        1            192.168.1.88:50680     192.241.181.178:443     users:(("chromium-browse",pid=4203,fd=41))                                     
LISTEN      0        128                     *:80                      *:*                                                                                      
LISTEN      0        128                     *:8080                    *:*
```

I'm not sure it tells much though. I tried to install `ss` from inside the container with `apk` but:

```
bash-4.4# apk add ss
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  ss (missing):
    required by: world[ss]
```

### EDIT 3:

Here is the result of calling `netstat`:

```
bash-4.4# netstat -plant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      229/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:32843        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      229/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      225/php-fpm.conf)

bash-4.4# netstat -plant | grep httpd
(nothing)
```

I'm not sure how much this helps though, since my other project, that works, yields the same result n `bash-4.4# netstat -plant | grep httpd`. Without the grep, it includes much more lines, though.

Comment: which container fails? which logs did you inspect? why is `# - ./docker/apache2/conf.d:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d` commented?

Comment: Can you please add docker file content?

Comment: @rok I guess you could say it's the `app` container that fails. However, the container runs. It's just that it seems the `traefik` or apache configuration are incorrect. What troubles me is, I can't tell what's really going on.

Comment: @rok The commented out line was written while debugging, it was an attempt to fix my problem that I forgot to remove here.

Comment: @RahulPatil I don't have a `Dockerfile`. However, I added the content of my override docker-compose file.

Comment: `ss (missing)` means that Alpine does not have this software in its repo catalogue. It is either under another name or you would have to install it from source, since binaries are not available. You may be able to use `apk search ss` from inside the container to see if it appears under another name.

Comment: Can you remove networks from all services? Docker compose will create network where all your services can reach each other by service name. So from your app container you can use ping traefik or rabbitmq.

Answer (score 2):

As the output that you have posted described the exposed ports `80,443,9000` for the container from this image `webdevops/php-apache-dev:alpine`

Then you can access the container using its IP directly from the browser. So first you need to ensure from the following:

- Check if `172.18.0.7` is the actual IP of `my-app-app` container, use the following command to check the IP of your running container

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' my-app-app
```

Or just `docker inspect my-app-app` to get all info about the container

- Check the logs for `my-app-app` and you may need to enter the container itself and check if apache is actually running by executing the following `supervisorctl` command which will tell you about the status of `apache` service

```
$ supervisorctl status apache:apached
apache:apached                   RUNNING   pid 72, uptime 0:07:43
```

If apache is running correctly then you should be able to browse the content using the container IP, in my case it gives me something like this as I don't have an actual application

[image]

Regarding your issue with `traefik` which is `Bad Gateway` that's because `traefik` itself cannot reach your backend service which is the `my-app-app` container in our case. you need to ensure that both `traefik` and `my-app-app` are within the same network or at least they can ping each other's IPs

Update:

Instead of `ss` it turns out the image contains `netstat` command, in order to check what port is used by apache you can do the following from inside the container:

```
# netstat -plant | grep httpd
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      98/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      98/httpd
```

Comment: Thanks, `docker inspect` is surely going to help. According to your answer, I think I can chalk off `Traefik` as the possible cause of the problem. Unfortunately, trying to call directly the IP from the browser still does not work... I edited my answer with the result of the commands you provided.

Comment: If this IP `172.19.0.5` does not work when called through the browser then are you sure that apache is actually listening on port 80?

Comment: From within the container, I did a `cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and saw a line `Listen 80`, so I guess yes?

Comment: @Zephyr I have updated my answer again with the correct command to use and what you should expect.

Comment: You have been the most helpful until now, so I'll award you the bounty. My problem still stands though...

Comment: @Zephyr I am willing to assist you in this issue, I will be waiting for the output of the ports using `ifconfig` just like the updated section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, deeply appreciated.

Comment: So... is it possible that I should define an apache vhost file to copy in the container?